# How to change the title of ToC Beamer?

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

I would like to change the title of ToC to "Outline" in Beamer class

```
\documentclass[leqno]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{How to change the title of ToC Beamer ?}
\author{Mohcine}
\institute{Tex.stackexchange.com}
\date{2017}
\begin{document}
 \maketitle
{%
    \setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
    \vspace*{-1.04cm}
  %\frame{\titlepage}
}
 \AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Table of Contents}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
     \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section[1]{1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
\end{frame}
 \section[2]{2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\frametitle{Outline}` instead of `\frametitle{Table of Contents}`:

```
\documentclass[leqno]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\title{How to change the title of ToC Beamer ?}
\author{Mohcine}
\institute{Tex.stackexchange.com}
\date{2017}
\begin{document}
 \maketitle


 \AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline} % <--- CHANGE HERE
    \tableofcontents[currentsection]
     \end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\section[1]{1}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
\end{frame}
 \section[2]{2}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Sample frame title}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]